# Change contents of BoxPanel in Swing

Tags: swing, scala

I am trying to remove a `label` from the `contents` of a `BoxPanel` in Scala-Swing but I am getting the following error.

```
value contents is not a member of Seq[scala.swing.Component]
 contents.contents -= label //Problem here
                 ^
```

I checked and found that it is a member of `scala.Seq`. Now I am not sure what is going wrong here.

```
def contents : scala.Seq[scala.swing.Component] = { /* compiled code */ }
```

My code is below.

```
import scala.swing._
import scala.swing.event._

object Starter extends SimpleSwingApplication {

  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "Swing Test APp"
    val button = new Button {
      text = "Click if you can"
    }
    val label = new Label {
      text = ") Clicks"
    }

    contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
      contents += button
      contents += label
      border = Swing.EmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30)
    }
    listenTo(button)
    var numClicks = 0
    reactions += {
      case ButtonClicked(b) =>
        numClicks += 1
        contents.contents -= label //Problem here
        label.text = numClicks.toString()
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to access `BoxPanel` via the generic `contents` method of your frame whose type is just `Seq[Component]` whereas the box panel actually implements the `SequentialContainer` interface that allows the mutation of its contents.

Simply keep a handle to your box panel directly:

```
def top: Frame = new Frame {
  title = "Swing Test App"
  val button = new Button("Click if you can")
  val label = new Label("0 Clicks")

  val box = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
    contents += button
    contents += label
    border = Swing.EmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30)
  }
  contents = box
  listenTo(button)
  var numClicks = 0
  reactions += {
    case ButtonClicked(b) =>
      numClicks += 1
      if (numClicks < 3) {
        label.text = s"$numClicks Clicks"
      } else {
        box.contents -= label
        box.revalidate()  // refresh layout
        box.repaint()
      }
  }

  pack()
  open()
}

top
```